# All maximal subgroups are complement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group such that for any maximal subgroup $M$ and a subgroup of $H$,

we have $MH=G$ or $MH=M$. Can we say something about this group ?

Note that the equality is claerly satisfied if $M$ is normal in $G$. Hence, if $G$ is nilpotent we have this property .

Comment: I see now that converse is also true. Sorry for trivial question.

Answer (score 2):

At first the question was interesting for me.

**Claim:** $G$ must be nilpotent.

Assume not. Then let $M$ be a nonnormal subgroup of $G$. Then we can take $M\neq M^g$. By the property, $MM^g=G$. Then we have $M=G$ contradiction.

Comment: First, I think you mean "let $\;M\;$ be a *non-normal maximal* (proper, of course) subgroup of $\;G\,$" . Second, clearly $\;MM^g=M\implies M^g\le M\;$ and this can't be since everything's finite here and $\;M^g\cong M\;$ . Finaly yet, why $\;MM^g=G\implies M=G\;$ ?

Comment: Let $MM^g=G$. Then $g=mn^g$ where $m,n\in M$. By simplifying, we can see $g\in M$. Hence, $MM=M=G$.

Comment: Hence, nilpotent group is just such group.